How to publish report from Pentaho PRD client take data from mysql to Pentaho server?
I created a report in the PRD client that extracts data from MySQL. The report works fine locally, but when I publish it to the Pentaho server using the client's publishing feature, I receive a fatal error message. I've confirmed that the server can connect to the MySQL database successfully. my server is enterprise version 8.2.0.0.342 and my prd client comumunity version 9.0
I created a basic report directly on the Pentaho server. and at prd client I get this file with repository connection, it still doesn't work.

I tried same JDBC on server and client still faced the same problem.

